# Google API grant function throws 'TypeError: Cannot read property '$k' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, exception, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google API {grant} function to request the calendar permission. The function never completes the network call and throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$k' of undefined
    at rl (cb=gapi.loaded_0:183)
    at pP (cb=gapi.loaded_0:215)
    at qY (cb=gapi.loaded_0:211)
    at WE.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:195)
    at new _.C (cb=gapi.loaded_0:104)
    at WE.W2 (cb=gapi.loaded_0:195)
    at WE._.k.sY (cb=gapi.loaded_0:195)
    at base.js:126
    at h.r2 (cb=gapi.loaded_0:107)
    at xs (cb=gapi.loaded_0:110)
```

The code seemed to work until a few days ago and nothing has really changed. Here is a minimal example creating the error:

```
function scheduleCalendar() {
  console.log("Schedule calendar");
  gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    gapi.auth2.init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: 'email'
    }).then(function (googleAuth) {
      console.log(googleAuth);
      googleAuth.signIn().then(function () {
        const googleUser = googleAuth.currentUser.get();
        console.log(googleUser);
        const options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder(
          {'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'}
        );
        googleUser.grant(options).then(
          function(success){
            console.log(success);
          },
          function(fail){
            console.log(fail);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What is at line: base.js:126? I would look there first and make sure you are passing the correct values or using the correct methods. Do you see any of your console logs?

Comment: Line 126 is the call to `googleUser.grant`. I used the code from the official docs [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth)

Comment: did you happen to type something by mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a regression in the Google API library. The problem seems to be fixed.